# Jump to specific data row in SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my result, I want to jump arbitrarily between the rows.

In my table, I have a field `next_set`. I start at row 1, which has `next_set=3`, so I process row 3 next, which tells me to look at row 2 afterwards, and so on.

In php/mysql I did this with mysql_data_seek. How do I achieve it in C# / SQL Server?

Comment: Assuming you intend on processing each row *at some point* just pull them into memory and then do your "row jumping".

Comment: one simple answer .. use `DATASET` instead of `DATARADER`

Comment: SqlDataReader is a fast lightweight forward only reader. You could loop through until current = next. But that would only work if next is never before you've read past. Need to rethink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot jump to some arbitrary position with `SqlDataReader`. From [MSDN description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Provides a way of reading a forward-only stream of rows from a SQL Server database.

You can only move forward one step at the time.

---

To get around the issue:

1. You can either read all records into memory and seek in memory collection.
2. Use a `DataTable` to get all records at once.

Answer (score 2):

`SqlDataReader` is forward-only, it does not allow jumping arbitrarily. However, you have several approaches that you could take here to overcome this problem:

- Read the data into a [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object which allows navigation of its [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects, or
- Read the data into an array, and navigate using array indexes.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` solution wouldn't work, it's always going to order by ascending or descending so if the actual order was something like `1, 3, 2` you would never get them in the correct order.

Comment: How can I use `ORDER BY` to get my rows in the order I need them in? Problem is that I have a reference chain. For example: 1 references 3, 3 references 2, 2 references 17, 17 references 12. If you know a SQL query which returns the values in the order I need them in, I would of course prefer that over a DataSet object.

Comment: @Alexander I am reasonably certain that this could be done, but I don't have time to construct an example at the moment. If you add a sqlfiddle.com test set, I may be able to get to it later in the day.